# How can I create an account on Parse.com ? There is no signup button?

Tags: parse-platform

I cannot find any signup button.
I gave right to Parse to access my Facebook and GitHub account to login with that but nothing happens and it keeps going back to the main page.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I suspect that they're not taking any further signups, although I may have missed some obscure sign up link somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @peter I kept looking around and I suspect the same...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you cannot currently setup a new account with Parse.com, because of some platform issues.

They have however open source a majority of the technology behind the platform. Check https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server to setup your self-hosted instance of the parse-server.

You can also check out http://firebase.com for similar service.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to create anymore. Parse is moving down.

But you can keep using Parse. At the same time Parse announced it will be shutdown, it also announced the Parse Server open source project. Parse Server community is growing and it is becoming even better than original Parse. In a short time, Parse Server will become the best framework for backend and API development.

My recommendation to you is to start using a Parse Hosting provider. Using this kind of solution you will use same Parse APIs and features. It will not require you learn other technology nor rewrite any frontend code.

You can find some options in parse server repository: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server#parse-server-sample-application

For a full disclaimer, I am co-founder of https://www.back4app.com

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in using their login page: https://www.parse.com/login

Answer (score 0):

Parse will be fully retired after a year-long period ending on January 28, 2017.
You cannot sign up or create new accounts, but you can use [Parse Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) in your own infrastructure.